# Angular 6 + set active for nested ngFor in unordered list

Tags: angular, ngfor, unordered

I nested *ngFor in an unordered list like:

```
<div *ngFor="let q of questions; let i = index;">
<label>{{ q.questionDesc }}</label>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [class.active]="active === j" (click)="onClick(j)" *ngFor="let c of q.choices; let j = index;">
    {{ c }}
  </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
```

My typescript code:

```
active: number;
  onClick(index: number) {
    this.active = index;
  }
```

When I select a "q.choices" item (c) in the inner *ngFor, the same item gets selected in all the lists. I only want a single item to be selected. I probably need to have a unique id assigned to each choice, not sure how can I accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: A question choice can be identified by its index (j) and its question index (i). Not just by j. So you need to store and test these two values. Or you could simply use an `activeChoice` inside the Question object, to know which choice of the question is the one that is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach, which stores the active choice in each `question` item of the `questions` array:

```
questions = [
   {
      questionDesc: "description here",
       choices: ["choice 1", "choice 2", "...etc"],
       activeChoice: -1
   },
   {
      questionDesc: "description here",
       choices: ["choice 1", "choice 2", "...etc"],
       activeChoice: -1
   },
   // ...etc
]

onClick(questionIndex: number, choiceIndex: number) {
   this.questions[questionIndex].activeChoice = choiceIndex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let q of questions; let i = index;">
   <label>{{ q.questionDesc }}</label>
   <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" [class.active]="questions[i].activeChoice === j" (click)="onClick(i, j)" *ngFor="let c of q.choices; let j = index;">
         {{ c }}
      </li>
   </ul>
   <hr/>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-co2rfr)

Comment: Thank you Horace, your solution worked great. Appreciate it.